# Struts 2.3.28.1 to 2.5 migration------support of jars in Struts 2.5

Tags: struts

I am migrating my project from Struts 2.3.28.1 to 2.5 and could  not find the below 3 jar files in Struts 2.5 bundle , which were present in Struts 2.3.28.1 bundle release.Can anyone let me know if Struts 2.5 still supports these 3 jars and if not, then any possible solution----xwork-core-2.3.28.1 , oro-2.0.8 , commons-validator-1.3.1.

Comment: Obviously not xwork-core. Looking at the showcase app it looks like validator and oro are still there, but that may be because of transient dependencies brought in by some other library. What's the specific issue?

Comment: the issue is...i have dependencies of the above thee mentioned jars in my application and since i cannot find these in the 2.5.2 bundle, i want to know if these are clubbed into some other jars or the previous version of the jars is supported in 2.5.2

Comment: Not XWork, which has been renamed and is part of S2 core. The dependencies you need for each version of S2 should be included transitively by the Maven `pom.xml` file--those are the libraries that are required.

Comment: @MohilM: You will have to update the rest of jar with latest version. post the exception in your question.

Answer (score 5):

`xwork-core` has been folded into `struts2-core`, thus there will no artifact for it with version `2.5.x`.

> XWork source was merged into Struts Core source, it means that there be no more xwork artifact nor dedicated jar

Check the release notes [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Version+Notes+2.5)